# Is the Holy Spirit the 'Seven Spirits' in Revelation 1:4?

Tags: exegesis, pneumatology, revelation, symbolism

> 4 John to the seven churches that are in Asia: **Grace to you and
>   peace** ***from* him who is and who was and who is to come**, and
>   ***from* the seven spirits** who are before his throne, 5 and ***from* Jesus Christ** the faithful witness, the firstborn of the dead, and
>   the ruler of kings on earth.To him who loves us and has freed us from
>   our sins by his blood 6 and made us a kingdom, priests to his God and
>   Father, to him be glory and dominion forever and ever. Amen. 7 Behold,
>   he is coming with the clouds, and every eye will see him, even those
>   who pierced him, and all tribes of the earth will wail on account of
>   him. Even so. Amen.
>
> Revelation 1:4-7 (ESV)

The text is saying that both grace and peaces comes from three people:

1) From the Seven Spirits

2) From him who is and who was and who is to come

3) From Jesus Christ

**Is the Holy Spirit the 'Seven Spirits' in Revelation 1:4?**

Comment: As it stands this is blatantly opinion-based.  You need to specify which tradition or denomination's perspective you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Isaiah 11:2 And the Spirit of the Lord shall rest upon Him—the Spirit of wisdom and understanding, the Spirit of counsel and might, the Spirit of knowledge and of the reverential and obedient fear of the Lord

1. Spirit of the Lord
2. Spirit of Wisdom
3. Spirit of Understanding
4. Spirit of Counsel
5. spirit of Might
6. Spirit of Knowledge
7. Spirit of fear of the Lord

[image: Seven Spirits]

Comment: Welcome Carl!  This is an interesting connection, but as it stands it sadly seems to just express your opinion.  Do any groups of Christians argue that this passage is connected to the Revelations passage?  If so, you should say who and cite sources. I hope you'll take a minute to learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and review [how to write a good, supported answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: How is it my opinion I quoted the only scripture that says what the seven spirits are and even gave an image that was not my own showing it. Here is info I pulled from a Jewish site about it.                                             "We can see a picture of the Menorah with its seven branches in Isaiah 11:2-3. The center of the menorah represents the Spirit of YHWH while the six other attributes are joined into the center pillar. These seven Spirits also signify perfection or completeness.

Comment: That's a reasonable Jewish interpretation; but we're specifically looking for the statements of Christian groups on the matter.

Comment: Hi, it's apparent that you want to participate, but may not quite get what the site is about.  I have a few links to help you along.:  [Newcomers: Be patient. You will get there if you follow our direction. Keep trying](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/), [help], and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/).  No offense, but I'm going to delete this simply because it doesn't match the scope of the site, but don't let that discourage you. Most of us didn't "get" this site at first, me included.

Comment: What I dont get is how when I gave the scripture references to back it up. And the references in the Jewish which is where Christianity stems from that it can be called my opinion and why it would be deleted. Are you saying that Doctrine is more important that the Bible? I read the document on What makes a good supported answer, and it sounds like the emphasis is on doctrine instead of the Bible which should be the final say for any Christian

Answer (score 0):

Revelation is a puzzling mystery, and this is just one of those questions we may never unlock.

Here's a post from [gotquestions.org](http://www.gotquestions.org/seven-spirits-God.html) that addresses this question.  They aren't sure what to make of it either, but they do give the verse you cited as a possibility:

> Question: "What are the seven spirits of God?"
>
> Answer: The "seven spirits of God" are mentioned in Revelation 1:4;
>   3:1; 4:5; and 5:6. The seven spirits of God are not specifically
>   identified, so it’s impossible to be dogmatic. Revelation 1:4 mentions
>   that the seven spirits are before God's throne. Revelation 3:1
>   indicates that Jesus Christ "holds" the seven spirits of God.
>   Revelation 4:5 links the seven spirits of God with seven burning lamps
>   that are before God's throne. Revelation 5:6 identifies the seven
>   spirits with the "seven eyes" of the Lamb and states that they are
>   "sent out into all the earth."
>
> There are at least three possible interpretations of the seven spirits
>   of God. The first is that the seven spirits of God are symbolic of the
>   Holy Spirit. The Bible, and especially the book of Revelation, uses
>   the number 7 to refer to perfection and completion. If that is the
>   meaning of the “seven” in the "seven spirits," then it is not
>   referring to seven different spirits of God, but rather the perfect
>   and complete Holy Spirit. The second view is that the seven spirits of
>   God refer to seven angelic beings, possibly the seraphim or the
>   cherubim. This would fit with the numerous others angelic beings that
>   are described in the book of Revelation (Revelation 4:6-9; 5:6-14;
>   19:4-5).
>
> ***A third possibility is based on Isaiah 11:2,*** which says, “The Spirit
>   of the LORD will rest on him — the Spirit of wisdom and of
>   understanding, the Spirit of counsel and of power, the Spirit of
>   knowledge and of the fear of the LORD.” This could possibly explain
>   the seven spirits of God: (1) Spirit of the LORD, (2) Spirit of
>   wisdom, (3) Spirit of understanding, (4) Spirit of counsel, (5) Spirit
>   of power, (6) Spirit of knowledge, (7) Spirit of the fear of the Lord.
>   The Bible doesn’t tell us specifically who/what the seven spirits are,
>   but the first interpretation, that they are the Holy Spirit, seems the
>   most likely.

Personally, I lean towards these spirits being angelic members of the Divine Council, but that is by no means clear.

> PSALM 89
>
> 5Let the heavens praise your wonders, O LORD, your faithfulness in the
>   assembly of the holy ones! 6For who in the skies can be compared to
>   the LORD? Who among the heavenly beings is like the LORD, 7 God
>   greatly to be feared in ***the council of the holy ones***, and awesome
>   above ***all who are around him?***